# Reverse a list in python

Tags: python

How to reverse a list in python? I tried:

```
a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
print a
a = reversed(a)
print a
```

But I get a `<listreverseiterator object at 0x7fe38c0c>` when I print `a` the 2nd time.

Comment: You sure you don't get `<listreverseiterator object at ...>`?

Comment: use slices: `a[::-1]`

Comment: Or you can do `a = list(reversed(a))`

Comment: @michael use .reverse()

Answer (score 2):

use 
  a[::-1]

its the pythonic way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

```
print a[::-1]
```

you could use this

Answer (score -1):

Python gives you a very easy way to play around with lists

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2013, 14:19:54)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ["abc", "def", "ijk", "lmn", "opq", "rst", "xyz"]
>>> a
['abc', 'def', 'ijk', 'lmn', 'opq', 'rst', 'xyz']
>>> a[::-1]
['xyz', 'rst', 'opq', 'lmn', 'ijk', 'def', 'abc']
>>>
```

And you can read up more on slincing in this very helpful SO post: [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)